# Count occurrences and associate with given array in C

Tags: c, arrays, count

I'm having issues to correct my code so that it works as I want it.

I have three arrays given in this example:

```
char arr[MAX_ELEMENTS][MAX_LENGTH] = {"ABS","ABS","ABS","ACT","ACT","PPB","PPB","QQQ","QQQ"};
char race[MAX_ELEMENTS][MAX_LENGTH] = {"PARI", "PARI", "LOND", "PARI", "PARI", "CYKA", "LOND", "CYKA", "PARI"};
int freq[MAX_ELEMENTS];
```

I wish to create a function that can count the amount of occurrences of string elements in `arr[]` and store them in `freq[]`. Apart from that I also wish to know in what `race[]` there have been the most occurrences of given `arr[]`.

To demonstrate this here is an example of what output I wish to receive when the function works:

```
In Race [PARI] the highest occurence was [ABS] with 3 occurences!
In Race [LOND] the highest occurence was [ACT] with 1 occurences!
.....
```

Currently, I am able to count the occurrences of `arr[]` in `freq[]` but I can't associate them with their respective `race[]` and give that output..

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    count = 1;
    for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
    {
        /* If duplicate element is found */
        if(strcmp(arr[i], arr[j])==0)
        {
            count++;

            /* Make sure not to count frequency of same element again */
            freq[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* If frequency of current element is not counted */
    if(freq[i] != 0)
    {
        freq[i] = count;
    }
}
```

Giving me currently :

```
ABS occurs 3 times.
ACT occurs 2 times.
etc. etc...
```

But I don't know how I can associate them with the `race[]` and only count them if a given race.

Comment: Your question is unclear as (if `race[i]` corresponds to `arr[i]`) ABS occurrs only 2 times in correspondence to PARI, not 3 times.

Comment: Would be easier to write this in Java or C++, using maps.

Comment: It's a bit unclear but spontaneusly I'd say you should have an array of `struct { char arr[MAXLENGTH]; char race[MAXLENGTH]; }`

Comment: Basically, your desired output `"In Race [PARI] the highest occurence was [ABS] with 3 occurences!"` is not consistent with your description *"Apart from that I also wish to know in what `race[]` there have been the most occurrences of given `arr[]`"*. Following your description, the result should be more like `"[ABS] occurs 3 times, most occurences where in [PARI]."`

Comment: wait for a while I am writing it!

Comment: "Apart from that I also wish to know in what race[] there have been the most occurrences of given arr[]" What do yo mean? In your example, these two arrays have nothing in common. It isn't clear how these arrays are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use `struct` here to format your data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define true 1
#define len 100
#define elms 10
struct NODE;
#define  Node struct NODE
struct NODE {
    unsigned long int val;
    int count;
    char name[len];
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node * makeNode(char * str, unsigned long int val){
    Node * tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(tmp->name, str);
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
    tmp->count = 1;
    return tmp;
}

unsigned long int getHash(char * name){
    int prime = 19;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long int val = 0;
    while(name[i]!='\0'){
        val += (name[i] * pow(prime, i) );
        ++i;
    }
    return val;
}
void insert(Node * root, char * name){
    Node * newnode;
    int val = getHash(name);
    Node * tmp = root;
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        if ( tmp->val == val){
            tmp->count += 1;
            break;
        }
        if (val > tmp->val){
            if( tmp->right != NULL)
                tmp = tmp->right;
            else{
                tmp->right = makeNode(name, val);
                break;
            }
        }else {
            if( tmp->left != NULL)
                tmp = tmp->left;
            else{
                tmp -> left = makeNode(name, val);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

Node * find(Node * root, char * name){
    int val = getHash(name);
    Node * tmp = root;
    while(tmp != NULL){
        if(tmp -> val == val){
            return tmp;
        }else if (val > tmp->val){
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }else{
            tmp = tmp->left;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

struct Race {
    char name[len];
    char elements[elms][len];
};

char arr[elms][len] = {"ABS","ABS","ABS","ACT","ACT","PPB","PPB","QQQ","QQQ"};
char race[elms][len] = {"PARI", "PARI", "LOND", "PARI", "PARI", "CYKA", "LOND", "CYKA", "PARI"};
int freq[elms];

void copyArray(char dest[elms][len], char src[elms][len] ){
    int i = 0;
    while(strlen(src[i]) > 0){
        strcpy(dest[i],src[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node * root = makeNode("root", 0);
    int i = 0;
    while(strlen(arr[i]) > 0){
        insert(root,arr[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(strlen(arr[i]) > 0){
        Node * r = find(root,arr[i]);
        printf("found %s, count = %ld\n", r->name, r->count);
        ++i;
    }
    // make representation of race
    struct Race r1, r2;
    strcpy(r1.name, "PARI");
    {
     char  tmp[elms][len] =  { "ABS", "PPB", "QQQ" };
     copyArray(r1.elements, tmp);
    }
    strcpy(r2.name, "LOND");
    {
     char  tmp[elms][len] =  { "ACT" };
     copyArray(r2.elements, tmp);
    }
    struct Race races[2] = {r1, r2};
    i = 0;
    while(i < 2){
        struct Race * current = &races[i];
        printf("for %s", current->name);
        Node * max = NULL;
        int m = -1;
        int j = 0;
        while(strlen(current->elements[j]) > 0){
            Node * tmp = find(root, current->elements[j]);
            if( tmp != NULL && tmp->count > m) { 
                max = tmp;
                m = tmp->count;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        if (max != NULL){
            printf(" max is %s : %d\n", max->name, max->count);
        }else{
            printf(" max is None\n");
        }
    ++i;
    }


   return 0;
}
```

Basically you have to format you data, and specify link between them. Here I used `Binary tree` and `Rabin karp hashing` technique to store data efficiently.

`Binary tree` is best way to solve counting problem, since the search operation fairly cheap. and `Rabin karp hashing` technique will avoid string comparison every time.

And I create a struct called `Race` to store all related elements of that race.  so the algorithm is going to be.

```
let arr be array of elements
let races be array of races
for each race in races
    define related element

#find occurrence now
#Binary tree will increment count if element already exist.
let binary_tree be a Binary Tree
for each element in arr
    add element to binary_tree

# now we have all the elements with it's count
# let's iterate through races now
for each race in races
    m = null
    for element in race.elements
        node = find_element_in_binary_tree(element)
        if node is not null
           m = max(m, node)
    if m is not null then
       print m
    else
       print not found
```

Answer (score 0):

First, initializations, note the `[]`s

```
char arr[][MAX_LENGTH]  = {"ABS","ABS","ABS","ACT","ACT","PPB","PPB","QQQ","QQQ"};
char race[][MAX_LENGTH] = {"PARI","PARI","LOND","PARI","PARI","CYKA","LOND","CYKA","PARI"};
int freq[MAX_ELEMENTS];

int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); // get actual number of used items
int i,j;

int max = 0; // init max to 0
```

The main loop goes through `arr` and `race`, and whenever a dupe is found at `[j]` (after `[i]`), "invalidate" the dupe ("already processed") by setting its first char to `0` (empty string).

Note that `j` starts from `i` and not `i+1` to ensure `freq` is at least `1`, even for the first non-dupes items.

```
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    freq[i] = 0;              // ensure freq is 0 for any item
    if ( ! *arr[i]) continue; // skip already processed items

    for(j=i ; j<n ; j++) {    // j=i, not i+1!
        if (!strcmp(arr[i],arr[j]) && !strcmp(race[i],race[j])) {
            freq[i]++;        // update max if necessary
            if (freq[i] > max) max = freq[i];
            if (j > i) *arr[j] = 0; // invalidate that arr element
        }
    }
}
```

Finally display the max appearances, including ties

```
printf("Items at max=%d:\n", max);
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    if (freq[i] == max) { // skipped items are never displayed (max cannot be 0)
        printf("%s / %s\n", arr[i],race[i]);
    }
}
```

(no need to check for "invalidation" as `max` will be `>0`, and all invalidated items have `freq[i] == 0`)